# Why did Subaru suggest to run away with Rem?

Tags: re-zero

In episode 18, Subaru gives up on basically everything and suggests to Rem that they run away to live a happy life in another country. However, he knows that...

> they will all die if he doesn't prevent Emilia's death.

I know that Subaru has suffered a lot at this point and he's broken and hopeless, but surely he would know he would only get three days of happiness AT BEST before he dies again and starts over again. So why did he even think this was an option?

Comment: Just for clarification, you mean they would only get 3 days at best because of Puck saying that he'd destroy the world according to his contract with Emilia after she dies, right? Or why is it you think they'd only get 3 days, when he plans on escaping to another country?

Comment: @paulnamida If I remember correctly, the day on which Subaru's last checkpoint was placed, to the day the witch cult attacks and kills Emilia, is only three days. Maybe I'm wrong and I'm off by a few days, but my point still stands: Subaru wouldn't even have a week to enjoy whatever he was planning on doing.

Comment: Did Subaru only understood Puck's will to destroy the world after Emilia's death ?

Comment: @Nevios Pretty sure Subaru asked Puck why he's destroying the world, Puck explains himself and then left Subaru to freeze to death.

Comment: Maybe you're right though i don't remember. But even if he _knew_, i don't think he was able to reflect upon what he asked to Rem.

Comment: He was so stressed at that time. It is no surprise that he would have such flawed plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He said that because he was emotionally tired. He was confident that he couldn't do anything more than what he has done so far. At the moment, he didn't want to accept that he was going to die again and again, so he just wanted a little moment of relax with someone who really cares about him, in this case Rem.